# If A, B are $n \times n$ matrices and AB=BA.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If A, B are $n \times n$ matrices and AB=BA. A has n distinct eigenvalues. Then the eigenvectors of A are also eigenvectors of B?

Comment: Give it a try. Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.  What can you deduce?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A(x)=cx, B(A(x))=cB(x)=A(B(x))$, this implies that $B(x)$ is an eigeinvector of $A$ associated to $c$,  since $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues,  the eigenspace associated to $c$ has dimension 1, thus $B(x)=dx$.

Comment: "Since A has n distinct eigenvalues, the eigenspace associated to c has dimension 1". This comes intuitively to me, but is there any formal way to prove it?

Comment: Just a quick question. Are the eigenvalues of $A$ also the same as the eigenvalues of $B$? Or does this only imply for the eigenvectors? And if $AB=BA$ doesn't that imply the matrices are each other's inverses?